# Only 2 Clients connected, yet router shows 4 IP addresses in the DHCP list

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

There are at present 2 devices connected to my home WiFi network, my laptop and my Raspberry Pi. The MAC address table on my router configuration page shows 2 clients connected but my DHCP client list show 4, ranging from 192.168.0.100-104.
My laptop is 101 and my RPi is 103.

Have I been hacked and can't see the MAC address of the attacker or is it something other than that? I have a Tenda router.

P.S- I am also experiencing speed issues at random times.

Comment: I don't know your router, but it is common for routers to remember previous DHCP clients, so that it can reissue the same IP address if the device reconnects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was possibly the worst question anyone could have asked... Actually my router was set to refresh the IP address pool for each device connected after 1 day (or 24 hours), and this explains this. The IPs I see are of devices which were disconnected from the router earlier but their IPs weren't refreshed.